# Rsync only include files with specific string in name

Tags: rsync, synchronization

I want to use `rsync` to backup databases from my webserver.

I created a cronjob on the webserver that creates a `mysqldump` of the database and names it with the current date in the beginning every night. Files older than 30 days will be deleted.

Now I want to backup only the databasefile of the current date to my NAS via a cronjob.

How can I only include that one file? Or vise versa, how can I exclude everything except that one file?

My code for `rsync` is the following:

```
rsync -avz -h -c --include="*$(date +%Y-%m-%d)*" -e "ssh -p $PORT" $USER@$SERVER:$SQL_SOURCE $SQL_TARGET --delete
```

The filename for today thats on the webserver would be `2021-06-30_databasename.sql` 
But also every other file like `2021-06-29_databasename.sql` gets synced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than syncing a *path* (and then defining file name inclusion/exclusion patterns) simply point rsync at the single filename you want to copy...

```
 filename=$(date +%Y-%m-%d_databasename.sql)
 rsync host:/path/to/file/$filename  /dest/
```

Note that this won't do any clean up of old files in `/dest/` and a year from now there will be 366 files there